# Change PHP $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with htaccess only in sub folder, and leave the it without change in the root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, document-root

I have 2 websites. One is in the `/public_html` and the second in sub folder `/public_html/site2`.

I want to change the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in the `/site2` directory so its `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will start from `/public_html/site2` instead of `public_html`. BUT the first site that in the root directory, must be left without the change so it will have the original `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` that is `public_html`.

I am trying to change the `.htaccess` that under the `/site2` directory, but didn't find any solution yet.

Can you help, please?

Answer (score -1):

You could globally override that variable within PHP, by using the php.ini auto_prepend_file setting, which can also be set using .htaccess again:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file ./override_docroot.php
```

And that script would then "globally" adapt your environment:

```
<?php
   $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = "...";
```

**But I really recommend you to create your own constant like "APP_BASE_URL" like this:**

```
define('APP_BASE_URL','http://www.mywebsite.com', FALSE);
```

And then call it like:

```
<img src="<?php echo APP_BASE_URL; ?>/img/path/img.jpg">
```

Gook Luck!

Comment: its to many changes that I will have to do in many PHP files. I am trying to avoid that and make the change only in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Really? you can use "search and replace" in your IDE and search all $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] and replace by APP_BASE_URL... but if you really prefer change the global use this: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site2/

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]

Comment: @Rafael what you're saying definitely works and I don't have anything against that. But there are cases where this implemention is not possible, i.e. creating a framework or making a custom composer package. I'm commenting because I came here looking for the same as olegin but your anser doesn't provide the solution at all, just gives an workaround.